# Can I build a mobile app using node.js, angular and sequelize?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sequelize.js, mobile-angular-ui

I wonder if I could build a mobile app using node.js, angular and sequelize and how building mobile apps differs from building web apps? I started recently learning node.js, angular and sequelize..
Thank you!

Comment: They are much the same thing since when you build a "hybrid application" that is much like the client code that you would be writing for a regular web application and in terms of the Node.js or any persistent data storage on the server side that stays the same.  As answers below mention native development for making clients is another beast entirely as each platform has it's own base language and frameworks to build from.  Cordova adds a wrapper/layer between the web view and the device hardware to expose common device hardware to the client web-app code, but native gets best performance.

Comment: Thank you. So if I would use node.js in combination with angular, I would just build it as I would build a regular web application, just that it could be seen on a mobile device?

Comment: yup you would essentially write the parts the same way.  I would also suggest checking out ionic, it takes about 30min to an hour depending on if you have xcode or adb already setup to get the demo project working and can get a good idea of where you would write your code in the sample project and how the build tools will package up the final thing for deployment to app stores for/with you.

Comment: Thanks!! do you know if I can build it with a gps locator? I just couldn't think of any way ass long as I build it with node/angular

Comment: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/geolocation/ <-- this plugin for Cordova looks like it would fit the bill, can't say I've used it yet though.  https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-native <-- Also linked from the first page this might be worth investigating.  Some of the main devs on Ionic are very responsive both on the forums and in slack, they make money from a push notification service, but are legit :)

Comment: hmm I just can't see how the location of the user could be transmitted if he never downloaded anything and only 'opened' the mobile version of my app..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/119060/discussion-between-shaunhusain-and-javascript2016).

Answer (score 2):

Mobile apps can be created using HTML5 based technologies. You would not run node.js on a mobile device, you could have a node.js app running on a server that the mobile app can call for data and HTML templates.

Building an app in HTML5 is never going to give you the same performance as a native app like an IOS app in Swift but it can reuse a lot of code and templates between the web app and mobile ports between different OSs.

It is a big topic but short answer is that you can build mobile apps with Angular but node.js will only provide you the server side part of the app.

Answer (score 1):

The essential notion behind these tools is basically to *reduce* "mobile app" development *to* "web development," by applying *(as much as possible)* the exact same techniques to both environments.  "The display is furnished by a web-browser, controlled by CSS and JavaScript and so-on."

This *is* "one way to do it," certainly.

But, as you embark on your learning-curve, you should *also* know that there are *(several)* other ways to do it.  You should make it a point to explore all of them.  *(In due time ... in due time ... Rome wasn't built in a day.)*

- ***Native* Application Development** uses a vendor's supplied tools to produce an app that basically runs *only* on that vendor's hardware. *(Although, you should pay careful attention to Apple's [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), which certainly seems to *me* to possibly have "cross-platform intentions."
- **Cross-Platform Toolkits**, such as [Haxe](http://haxe.org) and [OpenFL](http://openfl.org), which are both so-called "transpilers." These tools take a common source-language format and compile it into *source code* for a variety of platforms, which are then fed *(if necessary)* to a platform-specific compiler tool.

The specific tools that I have cited here are by no means the only such tools now available:   this is a rapidly-evolving technology.

Answer (score 1):

there are a lot of ways to develop hybrid mobile apps. If you were familiar with angularjs, IONIC will be a nice choice. Ionic combines AngularJS (JavaScript by the way) with HTML5+CSS and uses Cordova to access native device functions. There are genera 3 steps to develop hybrid mobile apps. Firstly, we develop it just as we develop the web app. Secondly, we need to install the platform dependency( android SDK for android mobile, Xcode for ios or windows phone ) and install build tool such as Apache cordova ( enables software programmers to build applications for mobile devices using CSS3, HTML5, and JavaScript instead of relying on platform-specific APIs like those in Android, iOS, or Windows Phone). thirdly, using cordova to build your web app into ios or android mobile app.

However, the use of Web-based technologies leads some Apache Cordova applications to run slower than native applications with similar functionality.